# How to play mp3 file in a mvc project using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, audio

I would look at similar topics.But I don't understand. There are more than one project in mvc solution. I would like to play an audio file using javascript in cshtml in the "voucher" project.This file is in the "content" folder under the "main" project. I can relate to the projects at the controller level.But I had a problem with the view level.

```
<script>
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = ""; // I could not add the path of the file.
audio.play();
</script>
```

I've tried this way:

```
audio.src = "@Server.MapPath("~/Content/sounds/beep.wav")";
```

I've also tried using html5. But again I could not access the other project in the "src". I tried converting the audio file into a byte on the controller part. But I didn't have a useful result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serv like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult GetAudioFile(string filename)
        {
string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content($"~/Content/sounds/{filename}"));
            var bytes = new byte[0];


            using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath , FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            {
                var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
                long numBytes = new FileInfo(fileLocation).Length;
                buff = br.ReadBytes((int)numBytes);
            }

            return File(buff, "audio/mpeg", "file.mp3");
        }
```

And then in your java script code:

```
function Sound(source, volume, loop)
{
    this.source = source;
    this.volume = volume;
    this.loop = loop;
    var son;
    this.son = son;
    this.finish = false;
    this.stop = function()
    {
        document.body.removeChild(this.son);
    }
    this.start = function()
    {
        if (this.finish) return false;
        this.son = document.createElement("embed");
        this.son.setAttribute("src", this.source);
        this.son.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
        this.son.setAttribute("volume", this.volume);
        this.son.setAttribute("autostart", "true");
        this.son.setAttribute("loop", this.loop);
        document.body.appendChild(this.son);
    }
    this.remove=function()
    {
        document.body.removeChild(this.son);
        this.finish = true;
    }
    this.init = function(volume, loop)
    {
        this.finish = false;
        this.volume = volume;
        this.loop = loop;
    }
}
```

Also used like this way:

```
var url= 'ControllerName/GetAudioFile?filename=yourfilename '
var foo = new Sound("url", 100, true);
foo.start();
foo.stop();
foo.start();
foo.init(100, false);
```

Comment: I wrote the controller method. I copied javascript method. But it didn't work. Unable to access method in controller. The method(GetAudioFile) in the controller is not called at all. Code =>  `function Sound(source, volume, loop){...}

        var url = 'ControllerName/GetAudioFile/fileLocation=' + "@Url.Content("~/Content/sounds/notificationSound.mp3")";
        var foo = new Sound(url, 100, true);
        foo.start();`

Comment: You should changed controller name with your one controller I snapped in sample how you can do this, change this  'ControllerName/GetAudioFile/' with your own controller and actionresult also make sure your routing is true.

Comment: sorry I copied that part wrong. `var url = 'CommonController/GetAudioFile/fileLocation=' + "@Url.Content("~/Content/sounds/notificationSound.mp3")";
            var foo = new Sound(url, 100, true);
            foo.start();` Where does the part call the method of controller in Javascript ? I don't understand the logic of the code. Do not call any method in the Sound function?

Comment: There is still no part in the script calling the method. The code doesn't work that way.
I think I should follow a different way.

Comment: Do you know how to used javascript? anyway try this `function playSound(myfilename){
  var audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.style.display = "none";
  audio.src = @Url.Action("GetAudioFile", "ControllerName", new { filename = myfilename });
  audio.autoplay = true;
  audio.onended = function(){
    audio.remove() //Remove when played.
  };
  document.body.appendChild(audio);
}`

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you're trying to tell me. I'm newer in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i tried the following code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
var url = "@Url.Content("~/Content/sounds/notificationSound.mp3")";
    new Audio(url).play();
}</script>
```

The code worked when I refresh the page. Then I pressed ctrl + f5. But this time not worked. The error message is displayed on the screen. Error message :

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException